# what is the solution of this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am new to database field. I am currently learning mysql using Murach's Mysql. I came across following problem in the book but I am not able to figure out the correct query for solving it.

Write a SELECT statement that
joins the
Customers, Orders, Order_Items, and
Products tables. This statement should return these columns:
last_name,
first_name,
order_date, product_na
me, item_price, discount_amount,
and
quantity
.
Use aliases for the tables.
Sort the final result set by
last
_name,
order
_date, and
product_name
.

By far I have this query:

```
select last_name , first_name , order_date , product_name , tem_price,
       discount_amount, quantity 
from customers , orders , order_items product 
order by last_name , order_date , product_name
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Caan you add the create statements of the 3 tables?

Comment: This is really basic SQL, and I'm sure that the 590 pages long book you're referring too covers this. Hint, look for the `join` statement.

Comment: Maybe she is just trying to understand what Is the meaning or the query. Although, she should include in the question what have she tried

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen  Is there a use of cross join here ??

Comment: @JCalcines  i tried this : select last_name , first_name , order_date , product_name , item_price,discount_amount , quantity from customers , orders , order_items product order by last_name , order_date , product_name ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we are going to analize the query. Since you didn't specify the database structure, I'm going to do an aproaching.

"*SELECT statement that joins the Customers, Orders, Order_Items, and Products tables.*"

This is refered to the tables, this is in the **FROM** clause. You have to join them with **WHERE** clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers, Orders, Order_Items, Products
WHERE Customers.order_id = Orders.order_id
  AND Order_Items.order_id = Orders.order_id
  AND Products.product_id = Order_Items.product_id
```

"*This statement should return these columns: last_name, first_name, order_date, product_na me, item_price, discount_amount, and quantity* "

This part is refered to the **SELECT** clause.

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, order_date, product_name, 
       item_price, discount_amount, quantity
FROM Customers, Orders, Order_Items, Products
WHERE Customers.order_id = Orders.order_id
  AND Order_Items.order_id = Orders.order_id
  AND Products.product_id = Order_Items.product_id
```

"*Use aliases for the tables*"

This part involves the whole query and means that have to rename the tables (virtually and only form this query) and in every reference you have to use the new name.

```
SELECT c.last_name, c.first_name, o.order_date, p.product_name, 
       p.item_price, p.discount_amount, p.quantity
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o, Order_Items AS i, Products AS p
WHERE c.order_id = o.order_id
  AND i.order_id = o.order_id
  AND p.product_id = i.product_id
```

"*Sort the final result set by last _name, order _date, and product_name.*"

This part refered to th **ORDER BY** clause. You have to keep in mind the aliases

```
SELECT c.last_name, c.first_name, o.order_date, p.product_name, 
       p.item_price, p.discount_amount, p.quantity
FROM Customers AS c, Orders AS o, Order_Items AS i, Products AS p
WHERE c.order_id = o.order_id
  AND i.order_id = o.order_id
  AND p.product_id = i.product_id
ORDER BY c.last _name, o.order _date, p.product_name
```

Comment: Except you have just taught this beginner bad old fashioned join syntax, and the last time I looked listing 4 tables without any join conditions would result in 3 CROSS JOINS (i.e. a potentially awful Cartesian product); would you like to revise your answer?

Comment: By the time you was making you advice, I was making the changes. :) However, thank you for your revision

Comment: @JCalcines Thank you for the whole analysis of question.

Comment: @JCalcines this is much improved, however @Sonali you do NOT want to learn this old fashioned join syntax. All of the joins used here are `INNER JOINS` and the `FROM clause` should be using that syntax.

Comment: @Used_By_Already When you are learning about doing queries you starts in this way. After of you control **SELECT**, **FROM** and **WHERE** statements, you start to use joins. She is at the very beginning of learning SQL so, I'm sure this is the better way

Comment: we shall have to agree to disagree, what happens is the bad habits persist. stackoverflow themselves ask that we use standards compliant code. There isn't much more to learn if you stick with inner join, you just use ON instead of placing it into the where clause. However this debate won't be solved here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join for these 4 tables `Customers` , `Orders`, `Order_items` , `Products` but make sure there is a match between the columns in these 3 tables.

### Example of the sql query based on the given information. (Assume CustomerID is a match between the columns)

```
 Select A.last_name,A.first_name,B.order_date,B.product_name,C.item_price,C.discount_amount,D.quantity 
 from TB_Customers A inner join TB_Orders B on A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID 
 inner join TB_Order_Items C on B.CustomerID = C.CustomerID on 
 inner join TB_Products D on C.CustomerID = D.CustomerID Where D.CustomerID ='TEST111'
```

Comment: There are 4 tables to be joined.

Comment: Well, you can based on the sql query i provided and u can edit from there by adding D and C will continues inner join D by matching D customerID and C CustomerID

Answer (score 1):

Using ANSI standard join syntax:

```
SELECT c.last_name, c.first_name, o.order_date, p.product_name, 
       p.item_price, p.discount_amount, p.quantity
FROM Customers AS c
    INNER JOIN Orders      AS o ON c.order_id = o.order_id
    INNER JOIN Order_Items AS i ON  o.order_id = i.order_id
    INNER JOIN Products    AS p ON i.product_id =  p.product_id
ORDER BY c.last _name, o.order _date, p.product_name
```